# How to insert text in an Entry Widget from a function?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to insert text in an Entry Widget from a function? I tried to get the numbers trough the module.get and then return them to a function that show them through the .insert method. But they don't appear.

```
window = tkinter.Tk()

window.geometry('600x500')

lblOperando1 = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Operando1', bg = 'light grey', font = 'Comic 13', padx = 10, borderwidth = 1, relief = 'solid' )

lblOperando1.grid(column = 0, row = 1, pady = 40, padx = 20)

lblResultado = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Resultado:', bg = 'light grey', font = 'Comic 13', padx = 10, borderwidth = 1, relief = 'solid')

lblResultado.grid(column = 0, row = 4, pady = 40, padx = 20)

lblOperando2 = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Operando2', bg = 'light grey', font = 'Comic 13', padx = 10, borderwidth = 1, relief = 'solid')

lblOperando2.grid(column = 0, row = 2, pady = 85)

entryOperando1 = tkinter.Entry(window)

entryOperando1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

entryOperando2 = tkinter.Entry(window)

entryOperando2.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

entryResult = tkinter.Entry(window, state = 'readonly')

entryResult.grid(column = 1, row = 4)

def result (n):
    entryResult.insert(0,n)

def Add ():
    n1 = int(entryOperando1.get())
    n2 = int(entryOperando2.get())
    n3 = n1 + n2
    return result (n3)  


buttonAdd = tkinter.Button(window, text = '+', bg = 'light grey', padx = 10, command = 'Add')

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to insert text in an Entry Widget from a function?

You are doing it correctly. However, because you've set the state of `entryResult` to `readonly`, you must first change the state to "normal", insert the text, and change it back.

```
def result (n):
    entryResult.configure(state="normal")
    entryResult.insert(0,n)
    entryResult.configure(state="readonly")
```

You also have the problem that you don't call `grid` on the button, and you've set the command to a string rather than a function. The `command` needs to be `Add`, not `'Add'`.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I change from state normal to readonly? I have to copy       
  entryResult = tkinter.Entry(window, state = 'readonly') again inside the function add?